# AngularJs - directive .compile does not instantiate ng-controller

Tags: angularjs

**Here is the plunker:**

**http://plnkr.co/edit/4SakSg6x5wuQQ5eYBwFN?p=preview**

**As you can see, I have two custom directives: child-one and child-two. The two directives are identical in all ways except:**

```
 1. child-one is within an html element that has the attribute ng-controller; and,
 2. child-two is not within such an html element, rather it's ng-controller is acquired thru the
    directive's .compile method, retrieving the controller thru the attribute var-ctrl.
```

**Child-one does populate with the items, child-two does not.**

**Question:**

What I must do to child-two, to make it function if I do not want the ng-controller outside of the directive?

Answer (score 0):

I think the directive attaches its own controller to the root element of the template (i.e., to `<div id="ctlrId">`), but you are also trying to attach another controller to that element using `ng-controller`.  I don't think that will work.  If you wrap your template in a `<div>...</div>`, then the HomeCtrl will be created:  [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EgK2ozPLlINycdAzwwjF?p=preview).  In the plunker, I added an `alert()` to the HomeCtrl to show that it is now being called twice.

But now you have a different problem: the $scope associated with HomeCtrl is now a child scope of the isolate scope.  So, all the attributes you have defined on the `child-two` element in `child2.html` will be undefined.  You can't define a controller inside a directive's template and at the same time try to pass properties from that controller's scope into the directive.

Comment: So you are saying my want to create a clean, elegant and all-encapsulating directive cannot be done? I have no choice but to exclude the controller from the directive? I have to resign to the fact that it must be outside the directive? Doesn't seem very elegant to me if so.

Comment: @Scott, your directive has to get its model data from somewhere.  Your choices are a controller (defined outside the directive like child-one) or a service, which you would inject into your directive.

Comment: Injecting a service seems like more work than is worth, I will just have a div o/s the directive defining the controller.